# is not mount my usb modem?

Tags: usb, mount, usb-modem

Already i see many questions about it .
But i cannot solve it .
here is my error :

```
Error mounting /dev/sr1 at /media/istiaq/GP Internet: Command-line `mount -t "iso9660" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,mode=0400,dmode=0500" "/dev/sr1" "/media/istiaq/GP Internet"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: special device /dev/sr1 does not exist
```

after use `sudo ntfsfix /dev/sr1` 

I see :-

```
Failed to determine whether /dev/sr1 is mounted: No such file or directory
Mounting volume... Failed to access '/dev/sr1': No such file or directory
Error opening '/dev/sr1': No such file or directory
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... Failed to access '/dev/sr1': No such file or directory
Error opening '/dev/sr1': No such file or directory
FAILED
Failed to startup volume: No such file or directory
Failed to access '/dev/sr1': No such file or directory
Error opening '/dev/sr1': No such file or directory
Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdsk.
```

After use  `sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda2` , `sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda1`

```
Refusing to operate on read-write mounted device /dev/sda1.
```

Note that : Iam very new in linux :)

Comment: That partition `dev/sda1` or `/dev/sda2` is usually for your OS, the one you should be looking is `dev/sdbX` or so! What are you trying to do?

Comment: my usb modem is not mounting , so, what i do ??

Comment: Plugin that modem and then run `lsblk -f` and add the output to your question.

Comment: And please usb-modem are usually read only. Are you trying to connect to the internet... using this modem?

Answer (score 0):

try using `fsck` 
steps: 
but first login as root

```
sudo su
```

then:

```
fsck /dev/ur-drive
```

you can also force fsck upon system boot
do:

```
touch /forcefsck
```

dont forget that uh must do all these steps with your root privilages.

then reboot ur system and hold down the **SHIFT** key which will open the grub menu
form which uh must select the **ADVANCED OPTIONS FOR UBUNTU**

after that select the **RECOVERY MODE**. 
then select `fsck` it will pop-up with some dialogue box..
select **yes** .
you can then select **normal mode** to bootup ur system in the normal mode.

Comment: my usb modem & speaker is not mounting . thats my main problem . are you sure ,its will be working ??

Comment: if its for ur usb then do 'sudo mount /dev/sdb(or)sdc whatevr it shows uh there..cuz /dev/sda is ur partitions